# Cakephp loadModel bindmodel not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I have hasMany Through table which is Chats table with Chat model and I'm using loadModel in User controller to load Chat model then ran below query to bindModel with Chat.user_id and User.id :

```
$this->loadModel('Chat');

$this->Chat->bindModel(array(
  'belongsTo' => array(
    'User' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('Chat.user_id = User.id')
    )
  )
));

$lastChat = $this->Chat->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Chat.receiver_id' => $user_id['User']['id']
  ),
  'order' => array('Chat.id DESC'),
  'fields' => array(
    'Chat.id',
    'Chat.chat',
    'Chat.user_id',
    'Chat.receiver_id',
    'Chat.read',    
    'Chat.created'
  ),
  'group' => array('Chat.user_id')
));
```

I want to join those tables together but this does not seem to work in Cake way I tried with normal SQL query and it works fine.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: This works for me. Are you correctly setting the value of $user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the recursive property before the find? Eg:

```
$this->Chat->recursive = 3;
```

You may need to set this after `$this->Chat->bindModel`, but I am not sure if this will make a difference or not. You will also need to re-bind the User model before each find, if, for example, your find queries are run within a loop ...